# How to simulate Apple Watch disconnection from phone

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, watchkit, apple-watch

Is there any way to simulate the phone being disconnected from the Apple Watch - on the iOS Simulator?

The only thing I can think of so far is uninstalling the phone app while the watch app is running.

I'd like to know as I haven't seen a definitive answer on what the behaviour is when the phone disconnects e.g. what happens to data on screen on the watch - is it removed or does it stay there read-only.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find the post on the Apple Developer forums right now, but all indications are that you can't test that scenario in the simulator.

EDIT: Found it. This thread should help a bit: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/254576?tstart=0

Comment: Thanks. I'd seen that - it's still a bit conflicted, will only be able to definitely know by testing

Comment: Is the behaviors on watch OS 2 similar to before? As the extension is moved to the watch, I hope the apps can run without iphone being in range or connected. Can someone please confirm this?

Comment: The link is apparently broken.

Answer (score 1):

Just close the iPhone simulator once the simulators open and show paired connection